# What is the complexity of sum of Logarithm of an arithmetic series

Tags: complexity-theory

this is the arithmetic series:

$a/b,2a/b,3a/b,...,ba/b$

The new series:

$log(a/b),log(2a/b),log(3a/b),...,log(ba/b)$

I want the complexity of sum of the latter.

p.s: sorry about formatting.

---

edit 1: I realized that I need to provide more info:

$a,b \in \mathbb{N} $

$a>b$

a and b are not constants.
and the answer is something similar to :
$O(b*log(a))$

Comment: A series doesn't have "complexity". Algorithms have time and space complexity. You need to ask about some calculation that you want to perform. It's very unclear what you mean here.

Comment: @gnasher729 I want the complexity of the sum of terms in the series.

Comment: @optimum Is what you want an asymptotic evaluation (equivalent $\sim$, $\Theta (\cdot)$, $\mathcal{O} (\cdot)$, $\dots$) of $f_a(b)=\sum_{k=1}^b \log(k*\frac{a}{b})$ as $b\to \infty$?
I feel this may be what you mean by complexity, as an algorithm's complexity is often given under the form of such an asymptotic evaluation.

Comment: @eru-cs Yes this is what I'm trying to solve.

Comment: @optimum "Complexity" describes how hard it is to calculate. The "sum" or the "value" of a series is the sum of its elements. So following the comments, when you say "yes this is what I'm trying to solve" I don't trust this.

Comment: When you say "a and b are not constants" it stops making any sense at all.

Comment: @gnasher729 I just simplified the original problem that was doing binary search multiple times on a list. The time complexity of that problem is equal to the sum of expressed terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(a,b)=\sum_{k=1}^b \log(k*\frac{a}{b})=\log\prod_{k=1}^b \left(k*\frac{a}{b}\right)=\log \frac{b!*a^b}{b^b}=\log(b!)+b\log\frac{a}{b}=b\log a +[\log(b!)-b\log(b)]$

by Stirling's formula, $\log(b!)=b\log b -b +\mathcal{O}(\log{b})$

Therefore $f(a,b)=b\log a +o(b\log a)$ so $f(a,b)\sim b\log a$

NB: all asymptotics ($\sim$, $\mathcal{O}$ and $o$) are taken as $a,b\to\infty$ with $a<b$)

For a more precise evaluation than just an equivalent, replace Stirling's approximation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) with Stirling's bounds (same wikipedia article).

Answer (score 0):

The complexity of the former is constant. Since we are talking about an Arithmetic Series (a finite sequence of numbers where the difference between any $i+1$ and the $i$ element is constant) the sum can be calculated as half of the product between the number of elements in the sequence and the sum of the first and last

$$ \text{Given a sequence of numbers } s = (e_1, \ldots, e_n) $$
$$ \text{where for each } i = 1 \ldots n,\: e_{i+1} - e_i = const$$
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n e_i = \frac{n (e_1 + e_n)}{2}$$

For your specific example, the sum above will be:
$$ \sum_{i=1}^b i\frac{a}{b} = \frac{b (\frac{a}{b} + b\frac{a}{b})}{2} = \frac{a(1 + b)}{2} $$
That means that the sum of an Arithmetic Series can be calculated in a constant number of operations, no matter how many numbers in the sequence: $ \mathcal{O(1)} $

The second series of sums it's not anymore an Arithmetic Series, thus you need to calculate the following:
$$ \sum_{i = 1}^n log(e_i) = log(\prod_{i=1}^ne_i)$$
due to the properties of logarithms. In your case that will traslate to
$$ \sum_{i = 1}^b log(i\frac{a}{b}) = log(\prod_{i=1}^bi\frac{a}{b}) $$
In this case you will need to perform $n$ products (well $b$ given your formula...) and the final logarithm, so the complexity strictly depends on the input and linearly: $ \mathcal{O(n)}$

Comment: a and b are not constants . I edited for clarification.

Comment: @optimum my bad, I thought you wanted the time complexity of calculating such series...

Comment: @Giuseppe To be honest, your answer is perfectly fine, but the question leaves much to be desired.